# can't stop the python thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, class, thread-safety

I wrote the GUI python application similar to the following striped  program,

A thread to download the data from the URLs list is started, the URLs list sometimes is very big so the user may decide to cancel the downloading and resume it at another time, but when I stop the thread I can not restart or resume it

```py
 downloader.start()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 848, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
```

my question is how can write the safe start/stop/resume task thread for such downloading task

code

```py
def dataDataDowload():

  for i in range(0,len(urlList)):
    
    if not os.path.isdir(ProjectPath+urlList[i]):       
       os.makedirs(ProjectPath+urlList[i].name)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(urlList[i], ProjectPath+urlList[i].name+'data.dat')
  

class Download(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,arg):
        #super(Download, self).__init__()
        super().__init__()
        self.paused = True  # Start out paused.
        self.state      = threading.Condition()
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()

            
    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.isStopped():
                return
            dataDataDowload()

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set() 

        
    def isStopped(self):
        return self.stop_event.isSet()
        
    def pause(self):
        with  self.state:
              self.paused = True  # Block self.

    def resume(self):
        with self.state:
             self.paused = False
                 
    
downloader= Download()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for an request task is using the async io in a separate thread or process.
In separate thread connected with quite a pipe with main thread and process every available task (in this case new link request )
In a worker thread async io process the downloading the requested take and notify the main thread after finishing the job